# Mocking static methods + running parameterized tests = "no match found"

Tags: java, unit-testing, static-methods, powermockito

I have a unit test class like this:

```
import junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner;

@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class CustomerTest
{

    @Test
    @Parameters({
    "true",
    "false",
    })
    public void testMaritalStatus(boolean married) {


    }

}
```

Now, I need to mock some static methods, so I do this:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunnerDelegate;

@Before
public void setup() {
     PowerMockito.mockStatic(Helpers.class)
}
```

But in order to use that, I need to do this too:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class CustomerTest {


}
```

The problem: I get this error:

```
No match found

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:536)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:496)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.NotificationBuilder.determineTestMethod(NotificationBuilder.java:141)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.NotificationBuilder.access$000(NotificationBuilder.java:37)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.NotificationBuilder$OngoingTestRun.<init>(NotificationBuilder.java:85)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.NotificationBuilder.testStartHasBeenFired(NotificationBuilder.java:231)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockRunNotifier.fireTestStarted(PowerMockRunNotifier.java:109)
at junitparams.internal.ParameterisedTestMethodRunner.runTestMethod(ParameterisedTestMethodRunner.java:41)
at junitparams.internal.ParameterisedTestClassRunner.runParameterisedTest(ParameterisedTestClassRunner.java:143)
at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.runChild(JUnitParamsRunner.java:388)
at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.runChild(JUnitParamsRunner.java:366)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$2.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:143)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$2.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:136)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.withContextClassLoader(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:127)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.run(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:136)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
```

Comment: Don't mock static methods. Test them thoroughly on their own and then treat them as part of the main code path of the class under test.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a [bug](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/685) in *PowerMock*. Apparently, the **DisplayName** for a method passed to *PowerMock* by *JUnitParams* does not match its rather narrow requirements. The following workaround is given:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <JUnitParams.flat>true</JUnitParams.flat>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This gives us:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
        <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<!-- workaround -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <JUnitParams.flat>true</JUnitParams.flat>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

With this in my `pom.xml`, and after adding `@PrepareForTest(Helpers.class)` to `CustomerTest`, tests are running fine:

```
import junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner;
import junitparams.Parameters;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunnerDelegate;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Helpers.class)
public class CustomerTest {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Helpers.class);
    }

    @Test
    @Parameters({
            "true",
            "false",
    })
    public void testMaritalStatus(boolean married) {

    }
}
```

Comment: What effect does setting flat = true have? I hate to set this property only to find out it has some side-effect elsewhere.